# Windows Failover Cluster API still Valid?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services, failover, failovercluster

I was looking for options for deploying. Net Windows Service under 2 windows failover clusters instances. But I stuck with Windows Failure Cluster API usage for communicating across windows service instances. I couldn't see any Ref. use it.  Is it still valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preferred method is by calling the [Powershell Cmdlets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/failoverclusters/?view=win10-ps) from your code.

Here's a class I wrote to cluster a virtual machine. It should give you enough to build on to get to where you want to go.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Management.Automation;


public static class FailoverClustering
{
    public static List<string> GetClusterNode(string cluster)
    {
        List<string> nodes = new List<string>();

        PowerShell powerShell = PowerShell.Create();

        powerShell.AddCommand("Get-ClusterNode");
        powerShell.AddParameter("Cluster", cluster);
        foreach (PSObject result in powerShell.Invoke())
            nodes.Add(result.Members["Name"].Value.ToString());

        if (powerShell.Streams.Error.Count > 0)
            throw new Exception(powerShell.Streams.Error[0].Exception.Message);

        powerShell.Dispose();

        return nodes;
    }

    public static ClusteredVirtualMachine AddClusterVirtualMachineRole(string cluster, string virtualMachine)
    {
        PowerShell powerShell = PowerShell.Create();

        powerShell.AddCommand("Add-ClusterVirtualMachineRole");
        powerShell.AddParameter("Cluster", cluster);
        powerShell.AddParameter("VirtualMachine", virtualMachine);

        Collection<PSObject> result = powerShell.Invoke();

        if (powerShell.Streams.Error.Count > 0)
            throw new Exception(powerShell.Streams.Error[0].Exception.Message);

        powerShell.Dispose();

        return new ClusteredVirtualMachine(
            result[0].Members["Name"].Value.ToString(),
            result[0].Members["OwnerNode"].Value.ToString(),
            result[0].Members["State"].Value.ToString()
            );
    }
}

public class ClusteredVirtualMachine
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public string OwnerNode { get; }
    public State State { get; }

    public ClusteredVirtualMachine(string name, string ownerNode, string state)
    {
        Name = name;
        OwnerNode = ownerNode;
        switch (state)
        {
            case "Offline": State = State.Offline; break;
            case "Online": State = State.Online; break;
        }
    }
}

public enum State
{
    Online,
    Offline
}
```

Comment: It helps. Thank you.